# No ColumnHeader.Clone in windows mobile?

Tags: c#, listview, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I want to make a copy of a `ListView` in Compact Framework 3.5, and while `ListViewItem` has a `Clone()` method, `ColumnHeader` has not. The full framework has this method for `ColumnHeader`.

Any alternative to `ColumnHeader.Clone()` on Windows Mobile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick clone :

```
// Manual clone
ColumnHeader ch = new ColumnHeader();
ch.Text = col.Text;
ch.TextAlign = col.TextAlign;
ch.Width = ch.Width;
```